# Making sense of jquery - constructor error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firebug

I'm pretty new to javascript, and has built a script that is working in webkit but not in firefox. When i check for errors in firebug, I get this:

```
google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor
    $('.to, .from').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
```

what does it mean?

Comment: is `google.maps.Geocoder` a constructor function? Could you show the relevant function?

Comment: Look more like a namespacing problem. Don't you include some scripts twice? A link to original HTML page or a copypaste of the smallest possible HTML page which still reproduces the problem would be helpful.

Comment: @BalusC - agreed. You can host it on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is a link to the original side: http://dev.resihop.nu/

Comment: Here is a link to the original side: http://dev.resihop.nu/ The function is intended to show a dropdown of adresses from google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function starts when APIs are not completele loaded, or you are not loading them at all :)
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/ - Here is an example, hope this will help you.